# postgresql : cannot execute a null querystring

Tags: string, postgresql, null

```
Create or replace function func1
return void as $$
declare
var1 character varying (255);
BEGIN
EXECUTE ' select column1 into '|| var1 || ' from table1';
END;
```

cannot execute a null querystring !!!

Answer (score 0):

`var1` is null here (because uninitialized), so concatenating it with text will return null.

No need for execute here, either:

```
select column1 into var1
from table1
```

Though if you do want execute in your real query, the syntax is more like:

```
execute 'sql statement' into var1.
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html

In both cases, note that you'll want to return a single row, else Postgres will complain.